# What kind of information can i find on android's Contacts Provider

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I am developing an android application and I need to know all the information about phone contacts.

I developed a function to get the name and number of all the contacts, but I need all the information about particular contact such as email, date, favorite or not, image, social links if available.

I got `id`, `name` and `number` from following:

```
String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
String number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
```

I used `ContactsContract.Contacts` to get _ID and DISPLAY_NAME, but
`ContactsContract.CommenDataKinds.Phone` to get the NUMBER. Is it correct?

Please explain the difference between the two methods.

Is the _ID a unique ID for all the contacts?

Comment: query this `Uri`: `ContactsContract.Data#CONTENT_URI`

Comment: how ? can u tell me an exemple ?

Comment: and how do you get *"the name and number of all the contacts"*?

Comment: `String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));`

Comment: so use the `Uri` i posted above to get the `Cursor` with the data

Comment: what is the type returned by `ContactsContract.Data#CONTENT_URI` ?

Comment: dont you have the API documentation in your SDK?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130350/discussion-between-torai-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long discussion with @pskink I finally found the solution to list all related information for each contact in the directory.
First of all, create a cursor:

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

And after that, you can dumb the cursor to show all the informations and see each contact and keywords it needs to use, like (custom_ringtone, display_name, photo_uri, is_primary, ..) by using this line of code:

```
DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);
```

Special thanks to @pskink